# Delete all lines in file with specific regex using sed

Tags: regex, bash, sed

**We'd like to delete all lines which matches with the following "regex input" and put them in a new file:**

```
Hi|thisisatest|11
```

**What we have:**

```
check='([^[:space:]]+)|([^[:space:]]+)|([^[:space:]]+)'
sed '/$check/d' test.txt > test_new.txt
```

It currently does not work.

Edit:

**We got the following test.txt:**

```
Jack|Miles|44
Carl|13
Robert|Whittaker|87
John|2
Frank|65
```

We want to delete `Jack|Miles|44` and `Robert|Whittaker|87`, which matches the regex (if the regex is correct).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct BRE regex is:

```
check='[^[:space:]]*|[^[:space:]]*|[^[:space:]]*'
```

Then use it as:

```
sed "/$check/d" file
Carl|13
John|2
Frank|65
```

btw `awk` can handle it even better without using regex. Just use `|` as delimiter and delete all line that don't have 2 fields:

```
awk -F '|' 'NF==2' file

Carl|13
John|2
Frank|65
```

Comment: Works perfect, thx alot. I'll check this as an answer when it's possible in some minutes.

Comment: One mini question: How to echo the out-sorted numbers only to an file? Like from Robert|Whittaker|87 - echo "87" to numbers.txt.

Comment: `awk -F '|' 'NF==2{print $2}' file > output.txt`

Comment: With that way we get the 13, 2, 65 from Carl, John, Frank, but what we need are the ones we sort out (delete) :)

Comment: Almost correct. Now we get "Miles" and "Whittaker", but not the number ;) Final way? /edited

Comment: Got it, it's awk -F '|' 'NF>2{print $3}' file > output.txt .. Thx for ur time! :)

Answer (score 2):

It is much more simpler when using `awk`, just do,

```
awk -F'|' 'NF<=2' file
Carl|13
John|2
Frank|65
```

To modify the same file back with the updates, just do,

```
awk -F'|' 'NF<=2' file > tmp && mv tmp file
```

Comment: Thx alot. anubhava's answer is more detailed so I'll check this as right answer to my question. But ur works fine too :)

Comment: I will do it so ;)

Answer (score 1):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -r '/\S+\|\S+\|\S+/d' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Also a `grep`:

```
grep -P '^\w+\|\d+$' file >tmp
```

selects the "correct" entries from a file e.g. `word|digits`

or

```
grep -P '^[^|]+\|[^|]+$' file >tmp
```

and rename the `tmp` back to `file`